# ASP.NET Button with no code reloads page in a new window when clicked

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, vb.net

I have a very simple ASP.NET project.  It consists of two pages.

The first page (*FirstPage.htm*) has the following markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function test() {
                window.showModalDialog('PageTwo.aspx', '', '');
            };
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="test();">Test Window</a>
</body>
</html>
```

The second page (*PageTwo.aspx*) has this as markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="PageTwo.aspx.vb" Inherits="MyEmptyWebApp.PageTwo" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button 1" />


    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button 2" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this as the CodeBehind:

```
Public Class PageTwo
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

End Class
```

So page one has a hyperlink that loads page two in a popup.

Page 2 has a button that *should* do nothing.  However, when I click on the button a new window pops up and loads Page 2 again.

If I navigate directly to page 2, nothing happens.

I'm thinking I must have some odd configuration either in VS or in IIS that's causing it; but I have no idea what.

The solution is [here](http://www.o1solution.com/RayEmptyWeb.zip) if you want to download it and look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modal dialogue windows can not handle asp.net postbacks. check out this link

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/96c46e09-b383-4330-ae8d-99436cb6c330/aspnet-modaldialog-with-postback-and-return-values-to-parent-page.aspx

hope it helps

ps - here is a [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536759%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more info on modal dialogue

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the `AutoPostback` property on the button.

Comment: Why would it open in a new window?